# Removing scuff marks from paintwork

Tags: body-work, car

Hi could any one give me some advise on how to get rid of this mark please [image]

Comment: Is that orange paint on top of the black paintwork or has the black been scuffed away to reveal orange underneath?

Answer (score 1):

Get your hands on some good quality rubbing compound and wax (for afterward). You'll want to use the rubbing compound with a cloth to get all the scuff marks off and the wax will make it look good as new.

You can also use Brasso (or whatever the shops in your country sells for polishing up brass).

Comment: Many "clear coat safe" products that function as rubbing compounds not sold as "rubbing compound". I'd look for a "scratch remover" or "cleaner compound". In the US, Meguiar's offers ScratchX and DeepCrystal Paint Cleaner, either of which might be appropriate here. At any rate, buy something "clear coat safe"